# .NET WPF - Why do I need the .resource file when the .dll should be enough?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization

For the project I'm currently working, I am creating resource files (.resx).  I am using Resgen.exe and AL.exe to create .resource and .dll files.  The Build Action for the `.resx` files is set to "None".

The idea is to allow customers to provide their own localization if what we provide does not suit their needs.

The problem I'm having is that the .resource files are absolutely necessary in the delivered product.  I was under the impression that the .resources.dll file be sufficient.  Are the .resource files really needed in the finished product or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:  I have recently discovered that helper files were specifically looking for .resource files.  I have modified the code to use the .dll, but now strings are not being returned.  So now my question is "how do I access the .resources.dll to retrieve the strings?"

Comment: For what its worth you might as well write you're own localization and translation engine. It might be less work in the long run.

Comment: A .resource file is supposed to be an intermediate build file.  Created from the .resx file and then embedded into the satellite assembly.  You are doing something else, it isn't clear why.  Start by googling "wpf satellite assemblies" to find the way this is normally done.

Answer (score 0):

Are you following a guide that says to set the build action to None? That seems like a mistake to me. If the build action is set to none, then it cannot be included in the library assembly.

I would try setting them to Embedded Resource.

Comment: Thanks but we are trying to avoid embedded resources (long story).  I have just discovered that we have helper files that are specifically getting the information from the .resource file.  I have modified the code to look in the .resources.dll, but am not having any luck retrieving strings.  I have modified my question accordingly.